# [ResizeObserver is not a constructor]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, static-resources

I am using Pixi.Js and graphology using static resource in lightning aura component. While generation of graph using these libraries I am facing this exception ResizeObserver is not a constructor The code is working fine if I use the script tag and running it in html file.

Here is the code from cmp file :

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAc tion" access="global" >
<head>
    <title>PIXI</title>
    <ltng:require    styles = '{!$Resource.pixiStyle}'  scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.PixiGraph, 
                                                                 $Resource.graphology
                                                                 )}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div style = ' width: 100vw;
                  height: 100vh' aura:id="graph" class = 'graphClass'></div>
</body> 
</aura:component>
```

Here is js file :

```
({
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('script lodead');
    debugger;
    const colors = [
        "#1f77b4",
        "#ff7f0e",
        "#2ca02c",
        "#d62728",
        "#9467bd",
        "#8c564b",
        "#e377c2",
        "#7f7f7f",
        "#bcbd22",
        "#17becf",
    ];
        
        const graph = new graphology.Graph();
        const { nodes, links } = {
        nodes: [
        { id: "Myriel", group: 1 },
        { id: "Napoleon", group: 1 },
        { id: "Mlle.Baptistine", group: 1 },
        { id: "Mme.Magloire", group: 1 },
        { id: "Mlle.Vaubois", group: 5 },
        { id: "Lt.Gillenormand", group: 5 },
        { id: "Montparnasse", group: 4 },
        { id: "Toussaint", group: 5 },
        { id: "Child1", group: 10 },
        { id: "Child2", group: 10 },
        { id: "Brujon", group: 4 },
        { id: "Mme.Hucheloup", group: 8 },
    ],
        links: [
            { source: "Napoleon", target: "Myriel", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mlle.Baptistine", target: "Myriel", value: 8 },
            { source: "Mme.Magloire", target: "Myriel", value: 10 },
            { source: "Mme.Magloire", target: "Mlle.Baptistine", value: 6 },
            { source: "CountessdeLo", target: "Myriel", value: 1 },
            { source: "Geborand", target: "Myriel", value: 1 },
            { source: "Thenardier", target: "Fantine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Thenardier", target: "Valjean", value: 12 },
            { source: "Cosette", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 4 },
            { source: "Cosette", target: "Valjean", value: 31 },
            { source: "Cosette", target: "Tholomyes", value: 1 },
            { source: "Cosette", target: "Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Javert", target: "Valjean", value: 17 },
            { source: "Javert", target: "Fantine", value: 5 },
            { source: "Javert", target: "Thenardier", value: 5 },
            { source: "Javert", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Javert", target: "Cosette", value: 1 },
            { source: "Fauchelevent", target: "Valjean", value: 8 },
            { source: "Fauchelevent", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "Bamatabois", target: "Fantine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Bamatabois", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "Bamatabois", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Perpetue", target: "Fantine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Simplice", target: "Perpetue", value: 2 },
            { source: "Simplice", target: "Valjean", value: 3 },
            { source: "Simplice", target: "Fantine", value: 2 },
            { source: "Simplice", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "Scaufflaire", target: "Valjean", value: 1 },
            { source: "Woman1", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Woman1", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "Judge", target: "Valjean", value: 3 },
            { source: "Judge", target: "Bamatabois", value: 2 },
            { source: "Champmathieu", target: "Valjean", value: 3 },
            { source: "Champmathieu", target: "Judge", value: 3 },
            { source: "Champmathieu", target: "Bamatabois", value: 2 },
            { source: "Brevet", target: "Judge", value: 2 },
            { source: "Brevet", target: "Champmathieu", value: 2 },
            { source: "Brevet", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Brevet", target: "Bamatabois", value: 1 },
            { source: "Chenildieu", target: "Judge", value: 2 },
            { source: "Chenildieu", target: "Champmathieu", value: 2 },
            { source: "Chenildieu", target: "Brevet", value: 2 },
            { source: "Chenildieu", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Chenildieu", target: "Bamatabois", value: 1 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Judge", value: 2 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Champmathieu", value: 2 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Brevet", value: 2 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Chenildieu", value: 2 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Cochepaille", target: "Bamatabois", value: 1 },
            { source: "Pontmercy", target: "Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Boulatruelle", target: "Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Eponine", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 2 },
            { source: "Eponine", target: "Thenardier", value: 3 },
            { source: "Anzelma", target: "Eponine", value: 2 },
            { source: "Anzelma", target: "Thenardier", value: 2 },
            { source: "Anzelma", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Woman2", target: "Valjean", value: 3 },
            { source: "Woman2", target: "Cosette", value: 1 },
            { source: "Woman2", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "MotherInnocent", target: "Fauchelevent", value: 3 },
            { source: "MotherInnocent", target: "Valjean", value: 1 },
            { source: "Gribier", target: "Fauchelevent", value: 2 },
            { source: "Mme.Burgon", target: "Jondrette", value: 1 },
            { source: "Gavroche", target: "Mme.Burgon", value: 2 },
            { source: "Gavroche", target: "Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Gavroche", target: "Javert", value: 1 },
            { source: "Gavroche", target: "Valjean", value: 1 },
            { source: "Gillenormand", target: "Cosette", value: 3 },
            { source: "Gillenormand", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Magnon", target: "Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "Magnon", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mlle.Gillenormand", target: "Gillenormand", value: 9 },
            { source: "Mlle.Gillenormand", target: "Cosette", value: 2 },
            { source: "Mlle.Gillenormand", target: "Valjean", value: 2 },
            { source: "Mme.Pontmercy", target: "Mlle.Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Pontmercy", target: "Pontmercy", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mlle.Vaubois", target: "Mlle.Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "Lt.Gillenormand", target: "Mlle.Gillenormand", value: 2 },
            { source: "Lt.Gillenormand", target: "Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "Lt.Gillenormand", target: "Cosette", value: 1 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Mlle.Gillenormand", value: 6 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Gillenormand", value: 12 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Pontmercy", value: 1 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Lt.Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Cosette", value: 21 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Valjean", value: 19 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Tholomyes", value: 1 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Thenardier", value: 2 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Eponine", value: 5 },
            { source: "Marius", target: "Gavroche", value: 4 },
            { source: "BaronessT", target: "Gillenormand", value: 1 },
            { source: "BaronessT", target: "Marius", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mabeuf", target: "Marius", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mabeuf", target: "Eponine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mabeuf", target: "Gavroche", value: 1 },
            { source: "Enjolras", target: "Marius", value: 7 },
            { source: "Enjolras", target: "Gavroche", value: 7 },
            { source: "Enjolras", target: "Javert", value: 6 },
            { source: "Enjolras", target: "Mabeuf", value: 1 },
            { source: "Enjolras", target: "Valjean", value: 4 },
            { source: "Combeferre", target: "Enjolras", value: 15 },
            { source: "Combeferre", target: "Marius", value: 5 },
            { source: "Combeferre", target: "Gavroche", value: 6 },
            { source: "Combeferre", target: "Mabeuf", value: 2 },
            { source: "Prouvaire", target: "Gavroche", value: 1 },
            { source: "Prouvaire", target: "Enjolras", value: 4 },
            { source: "Prouvaire", target: "Combeferre", value: 2 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Gavroche", value: 2 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Enjolras", value: 6 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Prouvaire", value: 2 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Combeferre", value: 5 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Mabeuf", value: 1 },
            { source: "Feuilly", target: "Marius", value: 1 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Marius", value: 9 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Enjolras", value: 17 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Combeferre", value: 13 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Gavroche", value: 7 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Mabeuf", value: 2 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Eponine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Feuilly", value: 6 },
            { source: "Courfeyrac", target: "Prouvaire", value: 3 },
            { source: "Brujon", target: "Eponine", value: 1 },
            { source: "Brujon", target: "Claquesous", value: 1 },
            { source: "Brujon", target: "Montparnasse", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Bossuet", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Joly", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Grantaire", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Bahorel", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Courfeyrac", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Gavroche", value: 1 },
            { source: "Mme.Hucheloup", target: "Enjolras", value: 1 },
        ],
            };
            // const { nodes, links } = await (await fetch('socfb-Caltech36.json')).json();
            nodes.forEach((node) => {
            graph.addNode(node.id, node);
            });
            links.forEach((link) => {
            graph.addEdge(link.source, link.target, link);
            });
            
            // layout
            graph.forEachNode((node) => {
            graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "x", Math.random());
            graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "y", Math.random());
            });
            // forceAtlas2.assign(graph, { iterations: 300, settings: { ...forceAtlas2.inferSettings(graph), scalingRatio: 80 }});
            const positions = {
            Myriel: { x: -319.5938720703125, y: -554.8636474609375 },
            Napoleon: { x: -371.102294921875, y: -597.3857421875 },
            "Mlle.Baptistine": { x: -243.19654846191406, y: -412.5160217285156 },
            "Mme.Magloire": { x: -261.1895446777344, y: -407.1710205078125 },
            CountessdeLo: { x: -351.65069580078125, y: -608.175048828125 },
            Geborand: { x: -357.7313537597656, y: -632.88134765625 },
            Champtercier: { x: -331.6962585449219, y: -613.2356567382812 },
            Cravatte: { x: -374.6083068847656, y: -618.6746826171875 },
            Count: { x: -316.7993469238281, y: -627.67431640625 },
            OldMan: { x: -337.1902770996094, y: -638.0137329101562 },
            Labarre: { x: -196.04751586914062, y: -206.07435607910156 },
            Valjean: { x: -139.4636688232422, y: -131.9685516357422 },
            Marguerite: { x: -296.9861145019531, y: -11.065747261047363 },
            "Mme.deR": { x: -175.80589294433594, y: -204.32505798339844 },
            Isabeau: { x: -202.56765747070312, y: -184.3802490234375 },
            Gervais: { x: -175.2349395751953, y: -225.46409606933594 },
            Tholomyes: { x: -364.1100158691406, y: 229.74696350097656 },
            Listolier: { x: -497.5599670410156, y: 223.6985626220703 },
            Fameuil: { x: -483.51434326171875, y: 274.7868347167969 },
            Blacheville: { x: -454.1170349121094, y: 272.83612060546875 },
            Favourite: { x: -468.734375, y: 219.8541259765625 },
            Dahlia: { x: -500.7531433105469, y: 252.30413818359375 },
            Zephine: { x: -454.21685791015625, y: 244.15045166015625 },
            Fantine: { x: -342.15960693359375, y: 110.13361358642578 },
            "Mme.Thenardier": { x: -55.454769134521484, y: 20.180898666381836 },
            Thenardier: { x: 16.608823776245117, y: 19.00442886352539 },
            Cosette: { x: -105.6224594116211, y: 95.86400604248047 },
            Javert: { x: -71.88691711425781, y: -48.92572021484375 },
            Fauchelevent: { x: -108.65303802490234, y: -249.78720092773438 },
            Bamatabois: { x: -320.6305236816406, y: -151.48208618164062 },
            Perpetue: { x: -356.4841003417969, y: 52.70114517211914 },
            Simplice: { x: -264.0255126953125, y: 3.9145567417144775 },
            Scaufflaire: { x: -153.30738830566406, y: -216.76480102539062 },
            Woman1: { x: -158.19863891601562, y: -80.40625 },
            Judge: { x: -366.9010925292969, y: -232.15151977539062 },
            Champmathieu: { x: -336.9045104980469, y: -209.40663146972656 },
            Brevet: { x: -321.26422119140625, y: -233.02935791015625 },
            Chenildieu: { x: -365.0048828125, y: -203.91456604003906 },
            Cochepaille: { x: -343.866943359375, y: -249.0477294921875 },
            Pontmercy: { x: 59.57659149169922, y: 191.4292449951172 },
            Boulatruelle: { x: 9.156700134277344, y: 82.76083374023438 },
            Eponine: { x: 124.48265838623047, y: 10.975862503051758 },
            Anzelma: { x: 40.5140380859375, y: 56.05881118774414 },
            Woman2: { x: -149.51480102539062, y: -24.99604606628418 },
            MotherInnocent: { x: -137.12112426757812, y: -262.8317565917969 },
            Gribier: { x: -107.63961791992188, y: -336.37353515625 },
            Jondrette: { x: 512.7171020507812, y: -210.77003479003906 },
            "Mme.Burgon": { x: 445.8450927734375, y: -160.9846649169922 },
            Gavroche: { x: 271.94744873046875, y: -22.884611129760742 },
            Gillenormand: { x: -29.188657760620117, y: 156.00843811035156 },
            Magnon: { x: -71.35029602050781, y: 135.9672088623047 },
            "Mlle.Gillenormand": { x: -50.69566345214844, y: 195.80865478515625 },
            "Mme.Pontmercy": { x: 0.7528436183929443, y: 268.0276794433594 },
            "Mlle.Vaubois": { x: -75.28184509277344, y: 285.63482666015625 },
            "Lt.Gillenormand": { x: -8.336037635803223, y: 202.83279418945312 },
            Marius: { x: 149.59442138671875, y: 135.3687286376953 },
            BaronessT: { x: 70.03011322021484, y: 219.35992431640625 },
            Mabeuf: { x: 315.9121398925781, y: 98.8280258178711 },
            Enjolras: { x: 275.9970703125, y: 58.15005874633789 },
            Combeferre: { x: 385.9283752441406, y: 64.12553405761719 },
            Prouvaire: { x: 434.0696105957031, y: 46.24740219116211 },
            Feuilly: { x: 377.1950378417969, y: 102.29449462890625 },
            Courfeyrac: { x: 344.7767333984375, y: 129.05642700195312 },
            Bahorel: { x: 390.31787109375, y: 148.2519989013672 },
            Bossuet: { x: 339.99859619140625, y: 45.74384307861328 },
            Joly: { x: 417.08526611328125, y: 121.08226013183594 },
            Grantaire: { x: 457.9179382324219, y: 87.14999389648438 },
            MotherPlutarch: { x: 412.1767578125, y: 12.456450462341309 },
            Gueulemer: { x: 45.698734283447266, y: -97.7848129272461 },
            Babet: { x: 36.17210388183594, y: -66.52565002441406 },
            Claquesous: { x: 62.680694580078125, y: -43.426212310791016 },
            Montparnasse: { x: 82.17730712890625, y: -100.35445404052734 },
            Toussaint: { x: -147.5833740234375, y: -3.969088315963745 },
            Child1: { x: 373.2082214355469, y: -125.63217163085938 },
            Child2: { x: 359.4578857421875, y: -134.36244201660156 },
            Brujon: { x: 126.8355484008789, y: -74.54096221923828 },
            "Mme.Hucheloup": { x: 425.4888000488281, y: 80.81478118896484 },
            };
            graph.forEachNode((node) => {
            const position = positions[node];
    graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "x", position.x);
    graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "y", position.y);
});

const style = {
node: {
size: 15,
color: (node) => colors[(node.group || 0) % colors.length],
border: {
width: 2,
color: "#ffffff",
},
 icon: {
 content: "person",
 fontFamily: "Material Icons",
 fontSize: 20,
 color: "#ffffff",
 },
label: {
content: (node) => node.id,
type: PixiGraph.TextType.BITMAP_TEXT,
    fontFamily: "HelveticaRegular",
        fontSize: 12,
            color: "#333333",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
                    padding: 4,
},
},
edge: {
    width: (link) => Math.log((link.value || 0) + 1) + 1,
        color: "#cccccc",
},
};
    const hoverStyle = {
        node: {
            border: {
                color: "#000000",
            },
            label: {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(238, 238, 238, 1)",
            },
        },
        edge: {
            color: "#999999",
        },
    };

const resources = [
{
    name: "HelveticaRegular",
    url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zakjan/b61c0a26d297edf0c09a066712680f37/raw/8cdda3c21ba3668c3dd022efac6d7f740c9f1e18/HelveticaRegular.fnt",
},
];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("graphClass")
var containerValue = component.find('graph').get("v.value");
const pixiGraph = new PixiGraph.PixiGraph({
container: elements[0],
graph,
style,
hoverStyle,
        resources,
        });
  
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ResizeObserver is not supported in Lightning when using the Lightning Locker Service. You can check out the [Locker API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer). You might be able to fix this by using the new Beta [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro), which you can enable in Setup > Security > Session Settings > Use Lightning Web Security (beta) for Lightning web components. You will need to port your code to LWC. Alternatively, you can use the [lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:container/documentation) element and upload your HTML directly as a Static Resource.

Answer (score 1):

Even after enabling Lightning Web Security, I had trouble with this (even though it had worked before).
I cloned this polyfill repository:
https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer
and built it using

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install
tsc
```

Then I zipped the contents of the /lib folder, uploaded it as a static resource named "resize_observer", and used

```
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import import RESIZE_OBSERVER from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/resize_observer';
...
loadScript(this, RESIZE_OBSERVER)
```

in my LWC.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of [@MayTheSForceBeWithYou answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/403004/139715),

I had a library that I manage the build/bundle process of that used `ResizeObserver` that I was trying to get added to a LWC. Since I manage the build/bundle, I was able to install [`@juggle/resize-observer`](https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer) to my project and import it wherever I was using `ResizeObserver` to polyfill it and include it in my resulting bundle.